# Python - Run thread in parallel instead of sequentially

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

Code:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def main():
    print([threadID])
    time.sleep(5)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threadID = 0
    while threadID < 5:
        main()
        threadID +=1
```

Currently, it runs the first thread, then once it is finished it starts the next.

How can I get all threads to start at the same time?

Comment: You don't get any threading just by importing ``Thread``.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)

Comment: @MikeScotty thank you for the reply - Will read this now and try to implement

Answer (score 0):

I feel a little stupid but was never actually calling threading...

Code:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def main():
    print([threadID])
    time.sleep(5)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threadID = 0
    while threadID < 5:
        t = Thread(target=main)
        t.start()
        threadID +=1
```

Comment: While what you're doing here might work for trivial use cases, in general it's a better idea to let Python manage multiple threads when you want to use them like this. I'm linking to a [particular example in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example); while reading from the start is important, in my opinion this is the most useful practical example in there. `multiprocessing.pool` also provides `ThreadPool`, though the documentation is... not really there.